# SocketException in Flutter

Tags: flutter, socketexception

I have these exceptions on different phones, some correct way to handle them.

IOS:

- SocketException: OS Error: Bad file descriptor, errno = 9, address = api.larvia.ai, port = 50655
- SocketException: OS Error: Operation timed out, errno = 60, address = o373931.ingest.sentry.io, port = 57488

Android:

- SocketException: OS Error: Software caused connection abort, errno =
  103, address = api.larvia.ai, port = 47438
- OS Error: Network is unreachable, errno = 101
- SocketException: OS Error: Connection reset by peer, errno = 104, address = api.larvia.ai, port = 48882
- SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = api.larvia.ai, port = 37628

I have an application that has a timeout to upload images to the service and I think that is generating these exceptions, although I do have a try block, but the exceptions are still generated in production. Thanks for any help

Comment: The error seems with your network connection, try changing your network connection or check your server is up and running where you have been uploading your file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a "normal" iOS error due to the network connection being closed when the app goes in background.

You can read more about it here: https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/197